# Postgres Database server migration

Tags: postgresql

We need to migrate our existing database server (PG 12)  to a new server.
I followed this [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/app-pg-dumpall.html] article and created the dump as

```
pg_dumpall > alldb.sql
```

then copied the file `alldb.sql` to the new system and tried to restore using

```
psql -f alldb.sql postgres
```

and it failed with the following error messages

> psql:allbackup.sql:314: ERROR:  option "locale" not recognized LINE 1:
> ...3103" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LOCALE = '...
> ^ psql:allbackup.sql:317: ERROR:  database "XXXXX" does not exist
> psql:allbackup.sql:319: error: \connect: FATAL:  database "XXXXX"
> does not exist

What could be the issue?

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Postgres version 12

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but why are you reading the manual for version 8.1 if you are using 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CREATE DATABASE` statement did not accept a `LOCALE` parameter until PostgreSQL version 13. It fails in your case because the target server is version 12.

The `pg_dumpall` command put that parameter because its version is newer than 12, so it considers that you're going to restore into a version newer than 12. You can check the version with `pg_dumpall --version`

The solution is to **use the same version of `pg_dumpall` than your target server**. On Ubuntu, you might have several versions installed. Check if you have `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dumpall`, and if you do, call it directly with that full path.

If it's not installed, it can be installed with the `postgresql-client-12` package.

Comment: yes , you are right .. the postgres client we were using was version 14. Thanks a lot